# access 2010 convert "Jan" into 1/1/2014

Tags: ms-access-2010, essbase

I am using Access 2010 to transform some data from an Essbase pull in Excel. I want to be able to just copy and paste the raw data, then have Access change the date from a text of "Jan" to actual date format of 1/1/2014.

Is there an easy way to do this in Access 2010?

Comment: Cdate("2014/Jan/1") = 01/01/2014 Come back with some sample code / sql code.

Comment: I don't have sample code. I have a table with a field where the values are Jan, Feb, Mar.... and I want to convert it to a date/time. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You need to make an attempt at some. I have given you a good clue. Do not forget that MS Access has a query design window that helps you.

Comment: Please do not post an answer to your question in the question. There is no reason why you should not post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint Fionnuala.

I was able to get it to work as follows:

> CDate([TableName]![MMM] & "-01")

My result when [MMM] = "JAN" was

> 01/01/2014